# Runtime event handler in cpp?

Tags: c++, annotations

Working on a cpp project, where I need something like runtime event handler. My primary goal is to keep a track of various events that takes place in a sample program  and based on the events specific handlers are triggered.

These event triggering handlers/functions are not contributing anything to the global objective of the sample program, but are just keeping track over various events in the cpp sample program.

My question is it prossible to create soemthing like custom eventhandlers in cpp? 
If yes, is there any tutorial for creating such custom eventhandler?

eg:
Event are like failed to enter while loop. successfully entered while loop, created object, deleted object, changed global variable etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're meaning with the term _runtime annotation_ :-P ... Could you elaborate this please, ideally showing a code sample for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ya. there is nothing like runtime annotations, but I want to implement something that works similar to an event handler that works on runtime. I'm sorry if confused you by using the word annotation.

Comment: What is meant with this term actually?? There's plenty of techniques available to implement event handlers though (synchronously or even asynchronously). The starting point should be to provide some event-source/sink interfaces, and declare what should be an event at all. For more sophisticated samples of such techniques have a look at e.g. my [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/) state pattern framework. Your question seems way to broad to be answered concisely here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you can refresh my question. I am looking for events like failed to enter while loop. successfully entered while loop, created object, deleted object, changed global variable etc.

Comment: _"... events like failed to enter while loop ..."_ That doesn't make any more sense, without seeing code what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I don't have right way to explain my requirement, but I'm sure it is something that really makes sense. If I say I want an asyncronous logger does it makes more sense! Logger have no dependency on what my code is actually doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82137/discussion-between---and-ikis).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form of event handler is a registered callback function pointer:

```
enum Events {
    FailedEnteringWhileLoop ,
    SuccessfullyEnteredWhileLoop ,
};

typedef void(EventHandler*)(Events);
```

---

```
 void MyEventHandler(Events ev) {
    switch(ev) {
    case FailedEnteringWhileLoop:
        // Do something
        break;
    case SuccessfullyEnteredWhileLoop:
        // Do something
        break;
    }
 }
```

---

```
EventHandler evh = MyEventHandler;
bool whileLoopEntered = false;
while(condition) {
    if(!whileLoopEntered) {
        whileLoopEntered = true;
        (*evh)(SuccessfullyEnteredWhileLoop);
    }
}

if(!whileLoopEntered) {
    (*evh)(FailedEnteringWhileLoop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for events like failed to enter while loop. successfully
>   entered while loop, created object, deleted object, changed global
>   variable etc.

The C++ language itself does not track these kinds of things as "events". Generally speaking it doesn't provide hooks into any of the various fundamental activities that happen across code.

So to do what you're asking for requires building an infrastructure yourself and working it into your code in various ways. (Or finding someone else who has done the same sort of work already and made it available. Although you still would have to integrate it into your code.)

To give some idea of what might have to be done:

For creating and deleting objects you can override the `new` and `delete` operators. But that doesn't cover stack/local/etc objects. Otherwise you could wedge something the constructors and destructors of every class you want to track, or even have all of them derive from a common base class which encapsulates the tracking.

For changes to a variable, you would have to wrap that variable in a container which only exposes the ability to change it through member functions. Then those could be coded to raise events.

For entering loops... You're out of luck because a loop isn't an entity that can be extended or hooked. You literally have to put some kind of call at every loop you want to track.

As for the rest of the infrastructure, you would probably end up doing something like having all of those various "events" call to some kind of global logging object. If you need different things catch different events over the course of a program, then you might also need to build a way of registering and de-registering listeners (the listeners themselves being based on an interface to derive from or std::function or whatever suits your use case).

But in the end since there isn't an out-of-the-box way provided by the language, you might want to re-consider what you really want and what you hope to achieve with it. In fact you might be better off asking your question in terms how to accomplish the end goal you wanted this for rather than how to do this "event" system.